# How do i take certain number of lines using PHP?

Tags: php, file

I need some help in PHP code.
My case is like this:
I have a list of files in one folder, lets say

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

and so on..
The contents of these files are:

```
1 M 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
2 L 0.5 0.17 0.3 0.9 0.5
3 Q 0.5 0.5 0.65 0.5 0.8
4 V 0.7 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7
5 H 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.4 
6 R 0.2 0.5 0.15 0.5 0.5 
7 T 0.5 0.5 0.43 0.2 0.3
```

and so on..

And i have another file lets say *example.txt* with content:

```
>file1.txt_6
>file1.txt_7
>file2.txt_1
>file3.txt_3
>file2.txt_5
>file3.txt_2
```

So i need to check every line of *example.txt*, if the file name exist in the folder then i need to open the file and check if, for example, the first line of *example.txt* is *>file1.txt_6*, then i need to open the *file1.txt* and check where number 6 is in the *file1.txt* then i need to take the previous and next line of the line that contains number 6 and save it in a new file.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php

    $files = glob("/directory of file1,file2,and so on/*.txt");
    $array = file("example.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

        foreach($files as $file){
            foreach($array as $key => $value){
                $data = file("$file",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                $name = substr($value,1,9);
                $site1 = substr($value,11,1);
                if($name === $file){
                    foreach($data as $k => $val){
                        $site = substr($val,0,1);
                        if($site1 === $site){
                            //here is where i think i should put the code to take prev and next line
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

?>
```

Can anyone help me? I am confused. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `the line that contains number 6 ` do you mean exactly `6` is  `0.65` allowed..??

Comment: @siddhesh i have edited my post along with the code..

Comment: @TintuCRaju i mean exactly 6. I actually need the first number of each line of file1.txt

Comment: You can do an `explode("\n", $array)` to split the file into an array, with a new element for every line

Comment: @giegie try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $handle = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $line = str_replace(">","",$line);
            $line_a = explode("_",$line);
            $file_name = $line_a[0];
            $number = (int)$line_a[1];
            if(file_exists($file_name)){
                $contents = file_get_contents($file_name);
                $contents_array = explode("\n",$contents);
                foreach($contents_array as $ar){
                    $previous_line='Empty';
                    $next_line ='Empty';
                    $number_in_line = (int)$ar[0];
                    if($number==$number_in_line){
                        if(isset($contents_array[$number_in_line-2])){
                            $previous_line = $contents_array[$number_in_line-2];
                        }
                        if(isset($contents_array[$number_in_line])){
                            $next_line = $contents_array[$number_in_line];
                        }
                        echo "Searching on  ".$file_name."<br>";
                        echo "Searching for number : ".$number."<br>";  
                        echo "previous line is :".$previous_line."<br>";
                        echo "next line is :".$next_line."<br><hr>";                    
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                echo $file_name." not exist <hr>";
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        die('Error opening file');
    } 
?>
```

Open the `example.txt` file and read the contents line by line. Replace the `>` symbol and `explode` the line with `_` to seperate `file_name` and `number` to search. Then get the contents of the file and `explode` it with new line `\n` so that we can identify each line. Then compare the first character of the line with `number` to search. If there is match find previous and next element from the array which we get by exploding file contents with `\n`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier123 i understand hope my update was fine.. thank you.

Comment: @TintuCRaju it works.. thank you so much.. now, i want to ask further question.. what if the content of example.txt has two "_" symbol. For example file_1.txt_6, how can i separate them? i'm sorry i asked too much question, i am new at php. Thank you so much for your help..

Comment: assume the name of the files in the folder has two "_" symbol as well. So it would be, file_1.txt, file_2.txt, and file_3.txt. @TintuCRaju

Comment: then explode with `_` will give you one more element in array. So you have to use `$file_name = $line_a[0]."_".$line_a[1];` and number will be `$number = (int)$line_a[2];`  @giegie